# Calling JavaScript class' function from jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a JavaScript class like

```
MyClass = function() { }
MyClass.prototype.init = function(param){ }
MyClass.prototype.reset = function() { }
```

if I call these function from HTML page using `onClick="reset()"` It works nice. But If I call these functions from jQuery it is not working. Please suggest to me.
A sample call from jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        app = new MyClass();
        app.init(someid, url,
            "event_handling": {
                "event1":app.reset
            });
    })
```

along with the above, is it possible to add CSS rules like:

```
"css_class_names": {
                        style-1: "firstStyle",
                        style-2: "secondStyle"
                    }
```

If possible, then how can I apply style to the particular element which has the ID
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only declare the function. You never call it.

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: try "app.reset()" instead of "app.reset", its a function not a property

Comment: You have a syntax error in the example (missing `{`) in the app.init call.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He is missing an opening brace in `app.init` before `"event_handling"`. Edit: looks like a closing one too.

Comment: @Shurdoof: Er, quite. And the corresponding `}` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that when the app calls event1, it's going to call app.reset from a different context than what you had intended. In other words, in your app.reset, the "this" variable won't be what you intend it to be. The reason is that when you declare `event1: app.reset` it sets event1 to the function app.reset.

workaround:

```
"event1": function() { app.reset(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You haven't really shown your call from jQuery, but I'm going to guess something like:</s> Actually, you have, but the problem isn't with the jQuery call. See notes under the break below.

Assuming:

```
$("some selector").click(app.reset);
```

...where you're passing one of `app`'s methods as an event handler.

The reason it's not working is that within the call to the method, `this` won't refer to the `app` instance, it'll refer to the DOM element. In JavaScript (for now), `this` is defined entirely by how a function is called, not where it's defined.

You can give the function the correct `this` value during the call by using jQuery's [`$.proxy` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$("some selector").click($.proxy(app.reset, app));
```

Alternately, ECMAScript5 defines `Function#bind` for this:

```
$("some selector").click(app.reset.bind(app));
```

...but that requires that you're running on an engine that implements it, or that you have an ES5 shim in place.

**OR** you can use a closure if you happen to have one handy:

```
$("some selector").click(function() {
    app.reset();
});
```

There we're using the fact that you have the `app` variable lying around, by creating a closure over it (the function we pass as the event handler).

More (on my blog):

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

---

In your code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        app = new MyClass();
        app.init(someid, url,
            "event_handling": {
                "event1":app.reset
            });
    })
```

The above discussion applies to

```
"event1":app.reset
```

If at some point later you call `event1()`, `this` won't be `app`.

You can apply the fixes above, like this:

`jQuery.proxy`:

```
"event1":$.proxy(app.reset, app)
```

`Function#bind`:

```
"event1":app.reset.bind(app)
```

Closure:

```
"event1":function() { app.reset(); }
```